# PHP date_timezone_set outputs nothing

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone, timestamp

I'm trying to convert the timezone of a MySQL field (dates are formatted like this 2014-07-28 16:02:44 ) to GMT+00 /Lisbon/.
The problem is that when I try to use the following:

```
  $date = date_format($row['theDate'], 'Y-m-d H:i:sP');
  echo date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Europe/Lisbon'));
```

My output field is blank, I thought that it might be because the host server has disabled (don't know why, and costed me an entire morning rewriting) mysqli and other newer functions (though PHP version is 5.3.8 and if my memory isn't lying to me it should support them by default), so I had to go back to mysql. 
Anyway,  I can't convert the timezone, and the code doesn't seem to have mistakes and should work... Or shouldn't it?

Comment: False is returned from your call because you're passing invalid arguments, and echoing false doesn't display anything... if you're passing a date to date_timezone_set() it should be a datetime object

Comment: If you want to see errors, then enable error logging/display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
$date = date_create($row['theDate']);
date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Europe/Lisbon'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

In your code:

```
$date = date_format($row['theDate'], 'Y-m-d H:i:sP');
echo date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Europe/Lisbon'));
```

The first argument of `date_format()` should be a `DateTime Object`. I suspect that `$row['theDate']` is being considered just as a string.

Also since it is showing a blank screen you should turn on error reporting so that you can actually see whats going on.

Comment: error reporting is on, so I should see errors, and now using your code, "$date = date_create($row['lastUpdate']);
      date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Europe/Lisbon')); 
echo $date;"
it just stops outputting anything where $date should be...

Comment: check the value in $row['lastUpdate']

Comment: *wrong* I had error_reporting(0); on an included file and it affected the error reporting, the error now displays as 

_Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /home/mvide/public_html/DM/panel/panelInit.php on line 424_

Comment: the value lastUpdate is properly formatted, when I echo it outputs (in this case) "2014-07-29 09:33:06"

Comment: Does `date_create($row['lastUpdate']);` print correctly

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it displays the same error, _Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string_

Comment: Paste the whole new code you are trying to run, in the question. I think you are having type conversion issues.

Comment: `$date = date_create($row['lastUpdate']);      date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Europe/Lisbon'));
echo $date;`

Comment: You cannot print a datetime object like that. Print it using `echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');`

Comment: Thanks mate, finally fixed it!